# Rails extend model with separate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

So I have essentially 3 applications which I need to tie together (by using an Engine). A public website, a point of sale and a manager (to manage the other two). I'd like to create a "Product" model which contains all product details agnostic to wines. Then I'd like a "Wine" model which extends Product. In the database I'd have two tables...products and wines. The wines table would only have the attributes specific to the wine and a product_id which links it to the corresponding product table entry.

I get how to do this *without* one model extending another (through belongs_to and has_*), but I don't understand how I'd do this as a model extension.

Using Rails 3.2.11

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...stuff goes in here
end
```

**Wine.rb**

```
class Wine < Product
    ...how do I ensure that the products table attributes and the wines table attributes are separately updated/created/etc.????
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [citier](https://github.com/PeterHamilton/citier) gem supports multiple table inheritance just like you're describing.

[This article](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/) also has a tutorial on how to set up multiple table inheritance without a gem.

Comment: Citier seems like it won't extend beyond one MTI but maybe that's just my poor understanding of it - the article you linked to seems very promising!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "beyond one MTI"? I've used this in an app with multiple levels of inheritance but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Actually after rereading it I think I know where I went wrong. I think I see how it works now.